# Collect iterator as 2D array

Tags: julia

I'd like to create a 2D binary matrix, but Julia uses `collect` in an unexpected way and gives me a 3D matrix.

```
using Base.Iterators

collect(product(repeat([[0, 1]], 3)...))
```

**Output**

```
2×2×2 Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64},3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 (0, 0, 0)  (0, 1, 0)
 (1, 0, 0)  (1, 1, 0)

[:, :, 2] =
 (0, 0, 1)  (0, 1, 1)
 (1, 0, 1)  (1, 1, 1)
```

Iterating over the non-collected results however in the expected

```
for x in product(repeat([[0, 1]], 3)...)
    println(x)
end
```

**Output**

```
(0, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(1, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 1)
```

How do I collect the tuples of the iterator as a 2D matrix?

Comment: Which 2d matrix would you like to obtain?

Comment: A 2D matrix like the last one I printed in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
julia> X = product(repeat([[0, 1]], 3)...)
Base.Iterators.ProductIterator{Tuple{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}}}(([0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1]))

julia> X |> flatten |> collect |> x->reshape(x, (3,:))'
8×3 LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Int64,Array{Int64,2}}:
 0  0  0
 1  0  0
 0  1  0
 1  1  0
 0  0  1
 1  0  1
 0  1  1
 1  1  1
```

Note that in your particular case the rows of the final matrix just correspond to binary counting from `0` to `2^3-1 = 7`. You could simply construct the result directly:

```
julia> reduce(vcat, digits.(0:7, base=2, pad=3)')
8×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 0  0  0
 1  0  0
 0  1  0
 1  1  0
 0  0  1
 1  0  1
 0  1  1
 1  1  1
```

Comment: Yes, I was trying to generate a binary counting matrix. Actually I mostly care about having rows/tuples, not necessarily a proper matrix. But I also wanted an approach that would work for all kinds of items.

What would the product, repeat equivalent be of `[[a,b] for a in [0,1] for b in [0,1]]`?

Comment: `[x for x in product(repeat([[0, 1]], 3)...)] |> vec` to get a vector of tuples. If you want a vector of vectors you can do the additional step `collect.(flatten.(ans))`.

Comment: Or as one ugly beast: `collect.(flatten.(vec(collect(product(repeat([[0, 1]], 3)...)))))`

Comment: But really, .. why? :)

Comment: Tuples don't seem to work later on in the program. Either way you helped me. Thank you.